# iPhone accelerometer values are not consistent

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa

i am working on a accelerometer sensors in iPhone.here is the code i by which i am getting accelerometer data:-

```
if (motionManager.deviceMotionAvailable)
    {
        motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 10.0f;
        [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdates];
        [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                           withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion* motion, NSError *error)
         {

             //DLog(@"%f",motion.userAcceleration.x);
              DLog(@"x = %f,y =  %f,z = _%f",motion.userAcceleration.x,motion.userAcceleration.y,motion.userAcceleration.z);
         }
         ];
    } else {
        DLog(@"No gyroscope on device.");

    }
}
```

i have a problem like if i put my iphone on a table in a static position still on table i can see its values are changing. its values are not consistent.

Could anyone please tell me why the accelerometer x,y and z axis is changing even the iphone is in still position?

Comment: how much are they changing?

Comment: What values are you seeing, what values do you expect, how much are they changing by?

Comment: deviceMotionUpdateInterval is a NSTimeInterval (double), why are you going out of your way to assign a float? unrelated to your issue of course.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, When you use `Accelerometer` only, there is earth's gravity which influences `z` value of accelerometer. But `DeviceMotion` tries to compensate for this influence of gravity (i.e.tries to give more accurate value of `acceleration.z`) by performing some algorithm on raw data received from sensor.

But this algorithm is not 100% accurate and that is why even if you put your device on flat surface like table, you get some non-zero value. This inaccuracy is very low in percentage but still you will get result which cannot be simply ignored.

You may want to perform enough trials and get average values of them to compensate for it. Again, this average value will not solve the problem completely. For example, when device is moving(and not stable such when on table) you may get more inaccurate values.

BTW, this inaccuracy or noise is called `gyroscope white noise` or `white noise`.

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone's sensors are *remarkably sensitive*.

If you have speakers playing music or a computer fan (even the quiet retina MacBook Pro fan) running on the table, the sensors **will** pick-up the vibrations and interpret them.

You might want to check that the absolute value of the acceleration is at least a certain amount before starting to react in your application.

Answer (score 1):

The variation of accelerometer data will come from a least two sources:

1) Vibrations (even small) of the table the iPhone is resting on, and
2) Noise due to the physical nature of the accelerometer.  This can vary with temperature - referred to as Gaussian noise.

It appears the iPhone accelerometer data is in units of 'acceleration due to gravity', i.e. a value 1.0 would indicate an acceleration of approximately 9.8 m/s.  So if the iPhone is laying flat on the table (face up) the data should nominally be x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: -1.0 plus some noise due to the above sources.